# CloneZilla using

Tags: backup, manjaro, clonezilla

I have laptop with Manjaro kde.
1 SSD - system
2 HDD - different file

I want backup all files on SSD to HDD using Clonezilla. But how can I do it, if I must to unmount all disks?

I try different variants, but no result...

Comment: Where exactly did you go wrong following this? http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone You need to boot from a Clonezilla device, and nothing is mounted except that device.

Comment: @cricket_007 so I can't backup my system runing this sustem at this time? how can I save system on SSD like restore point?

Comment: Linux doesn't have "restore point" like windows. You can backup your files manually using good'ol copy-paste. And no, you can't have it running. Reason being: there's files that are opened and process that are running - you can't open/read those files while they are being used

Comment: @cricket_007 so, if I want to save system I need to do only when system is not working? Not very convenient...

Comment: Your two disks need to be unmounted and idle. What is inconvient about that?